# jQuery event with an exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input element and there is a blur event on the input element to hide the div and just show the value from input as a text in the div, which works fine.

Now I am trying to make the input element to work as a combo-box. When I click on that particular drop down button I don't want my input to blur as well as when I have similar input as date picker i don't want it to blur when i select the date from the datepicker calendar.
How can i make an exception for the blur event not to blur when the focus is on those particular elements?

Edit: **Worked using document.activeElement.**

Comment: Please show some code. Hard to help otherwise

Comment: You can find out what element current has focus with `document.activeElement`

Comment: @crush document.activeElement worked! Thanks a ton :))